# Using cgroup module in iptables cause "no chain by that name" error message

Tags: raspbian-stretch, linux, pi-3b+, iptables

Trying to use cgroup module in iptables rule cause "No chain/target/match by that name" message.

I'm using:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

running on Raspberry Pi 3B+.
What I'm trying to do is to set the iptables rule like this:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

And it give me the error:
**iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.**

What I've already tied:

- *iptables -m cgroup -h* - gives me the help about available cgroup options.
- when I'm trying to type *-m anystring* it gives me message *iptables v1.6.0: Couldn't load match anystring* so cgroup must be there
- *modprobe cls-cgroup* - gives no error message
- */sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls* - exist and I can assign PIDs to the tasks in it

While trying to add all other rules to mangle output, even with other modules, they are accepted. No matter what I will try, all is good as long as I try -m cgroup.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems you have used rpi-update and are using a potentially unstable kernel. Try again with stock Rasbian Stretch

Comment: It is unlikely that you will find someone that will help you with an unsupported experimental kernel. You can test it and tell us and the developers the result.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm currently dealing with the same problem, but I can't really find anything about it except for this question.

Comment: Net filters (nftables) is newer and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an experimental kernel and presumably firmware, probably from running `rpi-update`. There are outstanding issues with the 4.19 kernel.

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: I know I'm on experimental kernel. I decided to make this move after I saw that it fixes one issue I had running on 4.14 and yes, moving to 4.19 fixed my problem. Then I ran rpi-update recently. Few days ago I wanted to make some changes with network settings and I needed to use cgroup for the first time and had the problem from my main question.
OK, I've done what you said to revert kernel, it reinstalled correctly, then I restarted my device but when I wrote `uname -a` it still show exactly the same version as before and cgroup in iptables still don't work :(

Comment: I just dig into github and found this [link](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits/stable) It seems that the experimental version just moved to the stable. That's why my reinstall takes no effect. It seems the only thing that left for me is to report this issue with iptables and cgroup here [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=224931&sid=a7f83eaf30d8371a599677f79f3e9c8a) and just wait.